# jQuery Ajax sending empty data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a code that send a data to a php file and send it back again and print it as a response however when i send the data it is sent as an empty data i did not know what is the problem this is the code that i tried:

```
var resource = $('#resource').val().replace(/[\n\r](?!\w)/gi, "").split("\n");

function doRequest(index) {
    // alert(resource[0]); The data here is ok and it is not empty whenever the data is sent the response is empty !
    $.ajax({
        url:'curl_check.php?email='+resource[0],
        async:true,
        success: function(data){        
            alert(data);
            if (resource.length != 1) {
                removeResourceLine();
                doRequest(index+1);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
doRequest(0);
```

Comment: try logging resource[0] to see if it has a value before you send the ajax call in doRequest()

Comment: Do you get the correct result if you go to `curl_check.php?email=some@email.com` directly in your browser?  Also you should call `encodeURIComponent()` on resource since it contain special characters.

Comment: I guess the parameter name is different, check if your parameter name is same or not. In java email is different from Email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're not sending the data using the data property of the ajax call object like so:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { email : resource[0] }
    ...
});
```

you are sending it as part of the URL, so it should be picked up as a GET variable. in php, this looks like:

```
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : false;
```

that said, i'd suggest using the ajax data property and specifying the `type` property and setting it to `GET` or `POST`. you could also use [`$.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

Comment: and don't forget to validate/sanitize the input!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am not sure what is wrong with what you are doing but I am going to give you code I use to send data to php and get a response. I am going to do it with json because it is awesome. I hope it helps:

```
var resource = $('#resource').val().replace(/[\n\r](?!\w)/gi,"").split("\n");

function doRequest(index) {
    $.post("curl_check.php", {
        email: resource[0]
    }, function(data, result, xhr){
        if(result == 'success') {
            console.log(data.success);
        } else {
            console.log('post failed');
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

The php code:

```
$json = array();
$email = $_POST['email']; //Please escape any input you receive
//Do what you have to do
$json['success'] = 'YAY IT WORKED';
die(json_encode($json));
```